# REGEX PCRE Recursive expression for nested text matching

Tags: regex, pcre

So i am trying to do something like this (yes, including newlines):

Match #1

```
START
    START
        stuff
    STOP
    more stuff
STOP
```

Match #2

```
START
    START
        stuff
    STOP
    more stuff
STOP
```

This is how far i have come

`START(.*?^(?:(?!STOP).)*$|(?R))|STOP` with the parameters "g" "m" "i" and "s"

The problem is that i cannot match anything after the `STOP` wihtout matching the last "STOP" in the entire text.

Here is a regex101 example

https://regex101.com/r/vD4nX6/1

I would appriciate some guidance

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the problem is matching the last stop, you probably need to make all your matches 'non greedy', something like changing '\*$' to '\*?$' or using the capital 'U' parameter.

Comment: How about [`START(?>(?!ST[AO]).|(?0))*STOP`](https://regex101.com/r/vD4nX6/4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a pattern that matches your example:

```
^\h*START\h*\n(?:\h*+(?!(?:START|STOP)\h*$)[^\n]*\n|(?R)\n)*\h*STOP\h*$
```

using the `/mg` flags (live at https://regex101.com/r/iK9tK5/1).

The idea behind it:

```
^                                  # beginning of line
\h* START \h* \n                   # "START" optionally surrounded by horizontal whitespace
                                   #   on a line of its own
(?:                                # between START/STOP, every line is either "normal"
                                   #   or a recursive START/STOP block
    \h*+                           # a normal line starts with optional horizontal whitespace
    (?!                            #   ... not followed by ...
        (?: START | STOP ) \h* $   #   "START" or "STOP" on their own
    )
    [^\n]* \n                      # any characters, then a newline
|
    (?R) \n                        # otherwise it's a recursive START/STOP block
)*                                 # we can have as many items as we want between START/STOP
\h* STOP \h*                       # "STOP" optionally surrounded by horizontal whitespace
$                                  # end of line
```

I've made `\h*+` possessive in order to avoid accidentally matching `" STOP"` by 0 iterations of `\h*`, not followed by `"STOP"` (they're followed by `" STOP"` (with a space)). The `+` forces `\h` to match as many times as it possibly can, so it has to consume the space.

Alternatively you could pull `\h*` into the look-ahead: `(?!\h*(?:START|STOP)\h*$)`
That would also work, but then the look-ahead would skip over any spaces to see whether they're followed by START/STOP, only to have `[^\n]*` outside go over those same spaces again. With `\h*+` at the start, we match those spaces once, with no backtracking. I guess it's a micro-optimization.

Comment: Thank you for the idea behind it, this really helped me!